# Yii DATE field format form

Tags: php, yii

My MySQL have `birthdate DATE` field for users.
But in FORMs it show it as one simple text field.

```
<?=echo $form->textField($model,'birthday')?>
```

There is any way to Yii recognize DATE and format 3 select fields day/month/yeah?
I used cakephp and it did automatically, helping a lot the development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no automatic way that Yii does this. The easiest way to do this is to add 3 more fields to the model controlling the form, some thing like:

```
date_year
date_month
date_day
```

You can setup the rules to handle the ranges/limits/types in the model. On the form you can then use those 3 models as test inputs.  Once the form is submitted (most likely to your controller/action) you can then concatenate the 3 new model attributes to form the string/timestamp for your original model attribute:

```
$model->birthdate = $model->date_year."/".$model->date_month."/".$model->date_day
```

Another alternative is to use [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (which is built into Yii by default)

Comment: what do you mean auto select?